# JS - readAsDataURL blocks browser activity

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

While I am loading a File into the browser I want to show an animated loading gif to the user. But if the file is very big the browser seems so buisy, that the animation of my gif does not work. What can I do to visualise the loading?

HTML

```
<img id="loader" src="img/load.gif" />
```

JS

```
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onloadend = function(){
    document.getElementById('loader').style.display='none';
    var source = reader.result;
    document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', source);
}
document.getElementById('loader').style.display='block';
```

Comment: Why did you delete your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499969/js-readasdataurl-blocks-animated-gif) and re-post the same question just one minute later?

Comment: I could not edit the headline, sorry I'm very clumsy

Answer (score 0):

In theory, what you have should work, as the read operation is asynchronous. Maybe it's the onloadend callback that is blocking the execution. In any case, you could try this:

```
reader.onloadend = function(){
    document.getElementById('loader').style.display='none';
    var source = reader.result;
    document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', source);
}
document.getElementById('loader').style.display='block';
// Make sure to start loading only after the loader was displayed
// (give the browser a chance to repaint)
setTimeout(function() {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}, 40);
```

Comment: thanx, I checked it out, the gif is animated for short and then stops, when the loading begins

Comment: I suspect the bottleneck is  loading a huge data URL into an img element. Try using a canvas instead.

Comment: It also stands still, when I use canvas, but the loading is faster

Answer (score 0):

The loaded event should be hooked first. Try this:

```
reader.onloadend = function(){
    document.getElementById('loader').style.display='none';
    var source = reader.result;
    document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', source);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

document.getElementById('loader').style.display='block';
```